# Converting Xml To String.New Line per tag?

Tags: c#, xmldocument

i am creating `XmlDocument` by code and adding some tag. The structure is like this

```
<root>
 <test>
  <test1>a</test1>
 </test>
 <test>
 </test>
  <test>
  <test1b</test1>
 </test>
</root>
```

I convert the xml to string using this code

```
using ( var stringWriter = new StringWriter() )
using ( var xmlTextWriter = XmlWriter.Create( stringWriter ) )
    {
        xmlDoc.WriteTo( xmlTextWriter );
        xmlTextWriter.Flush( );
        return stringWriter.GetStringBuilder( ).ToString( );
    }
```

But when i inspect the generated string all the tags are on the same line.
Is there a way to tell it to export only one tag per line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter("file.xml",null);    
xmlTextWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
```